# pandas dataframe to features and labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is a dataframe which I want to convert to features and label list/arrays.

[image]

The dataframe represents Fedex Ground Shipping rates for weight and zone Ids (columns of the dataframe). 
The features need to be like below

```
[weight,zone] 
e.g. [[1,2],[1,3] ...[1,25],[2,2],[2,3] ...[2,25]....[8,25]]
```

And the labels corresponding to them are basically the shipping charges so,

```
[[shipping charge]]
e.g. [[8.95],[9.44] .....[35.18]]
```

While I am using following code, but I am sure there has to be a faster, more optimized and perhaps more direct way to achieve this, either using dataframe or numpy

```
i=0
j=0
for weight in df_ground.Weight:
    for column in column_list[1:]: # skipping the weight column !
        features[j] = [df_ground.Weight[i],column]
        labels[j] = df_ground[column][df_ground['Weight'] == df_ground.Weight[i]]
        j +=1
    i +=1
```

For a dataframe of size 2700 this code takes between 1 and 2 seconds. I am asking for suggestions on a more optimized way.

Comment: Please, provide an example that I can copy and paste into my terminal. Not this.

Answer (score 1):

First, make 'Weight' index and mix the index and the columns:

```
mixed = df_ground.set_index('Weight').stack()

#Weight   
#1       2     8.95
#        3     9.44
#        4     9.89
#....
#2       2     9.24
#        3     9.92
#        4    10.41
```

Now, your new index is your features and the data column is your labels:

```
features = [list(x) for x in mixed.index]
#[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], ..., [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], ...]

labels = [[x] for x in mixed.values]
#[[8.95],[9.44],[9.89],[9.24],[9.92],[10.41]])
```